# What are the limits of words (or characters) and images in LinkedIn articles?

Tags: linkedin

I am wondering what are the limits of words/characters in LinkedIn Articles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spoke directly with LinkedIn Support, that told me the following limits:

**Publisher (Article) post headline**: 100 characters.

**Publisher (Article) post body text**: 110.000 characters.

**Image or Photo Credit (Under Article Image)**: 250.

Comment: Great to know. Thank you.